# Import the names of the tables from SQL Database in ComboBox (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, combobox

I've tried to show in a comboBox a list of al the tables from my database (My database name is "SQL"). This is what I've tried so far, but it won't show anything:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NUC\MICROGARDE;
Initial Catalog=SQL;Integrated Security=True;");

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

            sqlCmd.Connection = con;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select table_name from information_schema.tables";

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you try this querry : "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" and in Debug mode check if you have rows returned.

Comment: Still nothing happens...

Comment: Query returns no rows?

Comment: Why you populating `ComboBox` inside of the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler of the same combobox?

Comment: It returns no rows...

Comment: Did you try to run the query from SSMS and did it return any results?

Comment: If I run the query directly in the database it shows me the all the names of the tables, but in my C# application it just won't show anything in the comboBox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code block which populate `ComboBox` seems working fine.

Only one problem i can see, that your code never be executed, because code placed inside `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler of your `ComboBox`
This event will never fired because you haven't items in the `ComboBox` and index never changes

Move you code to the `Form.Load` event handler

Answer (score 0):

*If* everything is fine other than that, `information_schema` should be upper case as far as I know.

```
Select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
```

I change your `table_name` to `TABLE_NAME` as well since you assign this to your `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.

Comment: @edy What do you mean by _not working_? You get any exception or error message? Did you debug your code and check your values line by line? Can you please be more specific about your problem?